# Can I fully automate a dev machine build of Zend Server with Vagrant?

Tags: vagrant, zend-server

I've seen some examples of using Vagrant to quickly build dev machines.  I see that the provisioning step in Vagrant allows you to "automatically install software, alter configurations, and more on the machine as part of the vagrant up process."

However, the final step of installing Zend Server involves opening a browser to Zend Server and setting the password and accepting the EULA.  Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: Yes, to the extent that I want an autocooked dev machine to facilitate programming.  It kinda crosses lines.  I believe it's something a programmer would be interested in more than an infrastructure person.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a few more minutes of research would have rendered this for me, but maybe this will save someone else a little time.

Zend Server CLI has a command in /usr/local/zend/bin/ called zs-manage that has a command bootstrap-single-server that appears that it can configure the password, EULA and order/license information, taking the browser out of the loop.

http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Server-6-IBMi/content/bootstrap-single-server.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is nice phar executable that has access to most of the Zend Server commands even ones not available in zs-manage

https://github.com/zend-patterns/ZendServerSDK

Answer (score 0):

The quickest route is to use one the following Vagrant Bases from github via one of the following (noting the versions of Zend Server included as well):

- [Zend Server 8 + Vagrant + Apache + php5.5](https://github.com/janatzend/vagrant-zendserver-apache-php5.5) (Zend Employee Contributed, NOT Bootstrapped, Ubuntu 14.04 x64)
- [Zend Server 8 + Vagrant + nginx + php5.5](https://github.com/janatzend/vagrant-zendserver-nginx-php5.5) (Zend Employee Contributed, NOT Bootstrapped, Ubuntu 14.04 x64)
- [Zend Server (configurable, default v7) + Puppet + Vagrant + MySQL + apache or nginx + Symphony + Zend Framework](https://github.com/zend-patterns/ZendServerPuppet) (Bootstrapped & ready to run, official Zend Patterns Github Repository)
- [Zend Server (configurable, default v7) + Vagrant + Chef + Berkshelf](https://github.com/zend-patterns/ZendServerVagrantBerkshelf) (Official Zend Technologies Zend Patterns github account, MySQL)
- [Zend Server 8 + MySQL + Vagrant via Ansible](https://github.com/jonathancsilva/ansible-zend-server)
- [Zend Server 7 + Vagrant](https://github.com/sndpl/Ansible-PHP-Dev-Image) (via Ansible w/ Debian 7.x, Nginx, PHP-FPM, MySQL, Redis, Memcached, MailCatcher, NodeJs, Java, Zend Server)
- [Zend Server 7 + Vagrant + Apache + PHP 5.4](https://github.com/kraigh/vagrant-zend-bootstrap) (Also includes )phpMyAdmin